# While cloning git repository it is cloning only from "main" branch

Tags: git, git-clone

While cloning the Git repository it is cloning from "main" branch where I have only the README file. But I have another branch and from that branch code, I want to get a clone.

But whenever I hit `git clone <repository_url>` it clones only the README file from the main branch.

How can I get a clone from another branch?

Comment: `git checkout branch_name`

Comment: Maybe you are just confusing the terms here. "cloning" means download the repository from a remote URL with everything in it. It checks out the default branch, otherwise your question would be why the cloned repo is empty. Switching branches can be done after cloning as well, you don't have to fully download a repository every time you want to checkout another branch. Check out a [git clone tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-clone).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this:
git clone -b netflix-gpt-poc <repository_url>